# What is the best replacement battery for iPhone 5s

Tags: battery, iphone

My battery is 300+ cycles on my iPhone 5s, and it is draining very quickly, even though I do not have much applications running, and not many of them use background app refresh. Where and/or how can I find a decent replacement battery for iPhone 5s?

Answer (score 2):

I would buy an replacement battery for your iPhone 5s from [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/iPhone/iPhone-5s-Replacement-Battery/IF124-002-4). They provide also the tools to replace your battery. It's a trustworthy company. Worked with their parts/tools many times.

> **COMPATIBILITY**
>
> All iPhone 5s Models (Not iPhone SE, 5 or 5c)
>
> **SPECIFICATIONS**
>
> Voltage: 3.8
>
> Watt Hours (Wh): 5.92
>
> Capacity: 1558 mAh
>
> Apple Part #: 616-0718, 616-0719, 616-0720, 616-0721, 616-0722,
>   616-0728
>
> **WARRANTY**
>
> One Year Warranty - This iFixit product is guaranteed to
>   function for one year.

*I do not have financial ties with iFixit!*

Comment: I think also that this would be the best solution, but I also will wait for other suggestions.

Comment: Can't get it from iFixit, since it is 70USD for shipping, so it's not an option for me. It's just to expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 5 has a limit of 800 cycles with its battery.
If you are experiencing that, I'd contact Apple Support and have them run a diagnostic test on the iPhone and test the battery.

If they detect any unnormal battery behaviors they'll let you know.

An iPhone backup, and restore should also be a useful tool if you still arent convinced that the battery is ok.